# Summing big-O-notation

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

prove or disprove

$$\text{If } f(n)=g(n)+h(n), \text{ then } O(f(n)) = O(g(n))+O(h(n)).$$

I have no idea about where to begin.

what are the theories which should be used here?

Comment: Did you try experimenting with some examples for f, g, h?

Comment: No. Actually I couldn't find any references to learn theories or find examples for them

Comment: Start by looking at the definitions.

Comment: $O(g(n))\leq c_1 \cdot g(n)$ for $n >k_1$ and $O(h(n))\leq c_2 \cdot h(n)$ for $n>k_2$.  Clearly $c_1\cdot g(n)+c_2\cdot h(n)\leq \max \{c_1,c_2\}\cdot ( g(n)+h(n)) = \max \{c_1,c_2\}\cdot (f(n)).$ You can also choose $k_3 = \max\{k_1,k_2\}$