# Asymptotic notation for summations

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, big-o-notation, summation

I am struggling to understand why this property of asymptotic notation is true

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not: see [Summation of asymptotic notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117326/755), [Why is $\sum_{i=1}^n O(i)$ not the same as $O(1)+O(2)+\dots+O(n)$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/113190/755).

But if each $O(f(k))$ term uses the same hidden constant, then it follows by expanding the sum: see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum, [Summing big-O-notation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/119217/755), and then apply them repeatedly.